# Duda con un error al hacer un calculo en Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

espero me puedan ayudar con el problema que tengo.
Pues estoy realizando un programa el cual tiene la funcion de resolver Triangulos Rectangulos. 
Una de las formulas que hay que colocar para poder obtener el cateto del triangulo es (ya despejada)= CatetoOpuesto / Tangente del Angulo.

Al colocar esta formula en el programa, al momento que ingreso los datos necesarios para que haga el calculo(la cantidad de grados y el valor del cateto opuesto), me sale un resultado que no es correcto.

Un ejemplo:

catetoAdyacente=  5 / Tangente de 30 grados

El cual da por resultado= 8.66.

Pero al hacer este calculo en Visual Basic, me da como resulta -0.78 (algo que nada que ver)

No se si alguien sepa qué puedo hacer para poder resolver este problema que tengo.

Voy a adjuntar capturas de como lo he hecho(código):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ejecución:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui adjunto el codigo:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Dim anguloA, anguloB, ladoA, ladoB, ladoC As Double
    anguloA = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    anguloB = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    ladoA = Val(TextBox4.Text)
    ladoB = Val(TextBox5.Text)
    ladoC = Val(TextBox6.Text)
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
        anguloB = 180 - anguloA - Val(TextBox3.Text)
        ladoC = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(ladoA, 2) + Math.Pow(ladoB, 2))
        ladoB = ladoA / Math.Tan(anguloA)
        TextBox2.Text = anguloB
        TextBox5.Text = Format(ladoB, "0.00")
        TextBox6.Text = Format(ladoC, "0.00")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StacOverflow , te recomiendo que agregues el código , y no imagenes, ya que esto no es bien recibido por la comunidad.

Comment: Gracias por por la recomendación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema son tus matemáticas y el uso de las funciones.

La función [math.Tan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.tan?view=netframework-4.8) recibe como parametros lo siguiente:

```
Public Shared Function Tan (a As Double) As Double
```

donde a es un valor que recibe un ángulo, medido en radianes. **No** es un ángulo.

La misma documentacion tiene un ejemplo de como hacer la conversion de un ángulo a radianes.

```
Dim angle As Double
Dim radians As Double
Dim result As Double
angle = 30
radians = angle *(Math.PI / 180)
result = Math.Tan(radians)
```

O sea, que en tu codigo, tenes que pasar el ángulo a radianes y despues usarlo para calcular la tangente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta amigo.
Me ha sido muy útil.